# Calling shell from awk is incredibly slow

Tags: bash, awk

I want to process a value in awk on the run.
Value is processed via binary.
I'm trying to do this following way but it is suuuuuper slow. Unusable slow.
5 million records without this processing finishes in 30 seconds. With it - I waited for several hours with no end result.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a correct way to process a value in awk using external app?

**bash call**

```
#!/bin/bash
...    
cat ${INFILE} | awk -F"\t" -v sh_dir="${DIRECTORY_PATH_SH}" outfile="${OUTFILE}" -f process.awk
```

**process.awk**

```
{   
    cmd=sh_dir"/sha_cipher"
    print $2 |& cmd
    close(cmd, "to")
    cmd |& getline encrypted_id
    close(cmd)

    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, encrypted_id, $19 >> outfile
}
```

INPUT:

> 2018-09-14 | AlexOrange | 15 | HTTP | 86914702 | 1 | 1 | NO | 79634 |
>   48249 | 127883 | LEFT | MODEL1 | SUBTYPE255 A536 | RS | SO | 94 |
>   Elixir | RTT

OUTPUT:

> 2018-09-14 | 36c8387b7e334c38786d6d497b | RTT

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: You are invoking a new process every time, with 5 million records that's 5 million child processes.  Those are not all running at the same time, but it does not reuse them.  Best I can suggest is that you use a language with the functionality of `sha_cipher` built-in, like python.

Comment: By the way, the `cat` is another unnecessary child process (not that it would make much of a difference when you have 5,000,000).

Comment: @Cyrus Added sample input and output. I changed tab separator to " | " for clarity.

Comment: @cdarke We have a dozen of established environments in different cities. There are some difficulties adding new tech. From management approval to deployment. Additionally we already have a number of tech used. We don't really want to increase tech stack - it has some bad consequences.

Comment: @cdrake Binary is not actual sha. :) It's internal implementation of an algorithm. So in any case I would have to call this binary.

Comment: @cdarke Is there a way to cache the command for awk? In order not to open subshells every time.

Comment: OK, what language is `sha_cipher` written in?  If something like C then what you are doing in `awk` would be trivial.  On cacheing the command, it really depends on your binary program.  If it will run in a loop continually pushing output for input then a `bash` or `awk` script could be used.  If the binary only takes one input and produces one output, then maybe that's the place to start changing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `sha_cipher` on my PC but let's imagine your shell command was `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` instead of `sha_cipher`. Look (tab-separated input):

```
$ cat file
2018-09-14      AlexOrange      15      HTTP    86914702        1       1       NO      79634   48249   127883  LEFT    MODEL1  SUBTYPE255 A536 RS      SO      94     Elixir   RTT
2018-09-14      Joe Bloggs      15      HTTP    86914702        1       1       NO      79634   48249   127883  LEFT    MODEL1  SUBTYPE255 A536 RS      SO      94     Elixir   RTT
2018-09-14      Sue Everyone    15      HTTP    86914702        1       1       NO      79634   48249   127883  LEFT    MODEL1  SUBTYPE255 A536 RS      SO      94     Elixir   RTT

$ cut -f2 file | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
ALEXORANGE
JOE BLOGGS
SUE EVERYONE

$ cut -f2 file | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print $1, a[FNR], $19}' - file
2018-09-14      ALEXORANGE      RTT
2018-09-14      JOE BLOGGS      RTT
2018-09-14      SUE EVERYONE    RTT
```

That will be orders of magnitude more efficient than having awk start up a subshell to call your shell command once for every line of input, assuming `sha_cipher` can operate on multiple values in piped input like `tr` and most other text-processing shell commands can (cut, sed, grep, sort, uniq, etc...).

To test timing I created a file with 5 million lines in the same format as your provided sample input line and containing random strings in the 2nd field by using:

```
$ cat file
2018-09-14      AlexOrange      15      HTTP    86914702        1       1       NO      79634   48249   127883  LEFT    MODEL1  SUBTYPE255 A536 RS      SO      94     Elixir   RTT

$ tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | fold -w 6 | head -5000000 |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{orig=$0;next} {x=$0; $0=orig; $2=x}1' file - > file5m

$ wc -l file5m
5000000 file5m

$ head -3 file5m
2018-09-14      fLSynM  15      HTTP    86914702        1       1       NO      79634   48249   127883  LEFT    MODEL1  SUBTYPE255 A536 RS      SO      94      Elixir RTT
2018-09-14      mxWzLF  15      HTTP    86914702        1       1       NO      79634   48249   127883  LEFT    MODEL1  SUBTYPE255 A536 RS      SO      94      Elixir RTT
2018-09-14      EKJYF8  15      HTTP    86914702        1       1       NO      79634   48249   127883  LEFT    MODEL1  SUBTYPE255 A536 RS      SO      94      Elixir RTT
```

and here's the result of running the proposed solution on it:

```
$ time cut -f2 file5m | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print $1, a[FNR], $19}' - file5m > outFile5m
real    0m40.892s
user    0m42.196s
sys     0m0.980s

$ wc -l outFile5m
5000000 outFile5m

$ head -3 outFile5m
2018-09-14      FLSYNM  RTT
2018-09-14      MXWZLF  RTT
2018-09-14      EKJYF8  RTT
```

So unless `sha_cipher` is far less efficient than `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` (if it is then you're just out of luck) then I expect the above should run fast enough for you (i.e. it should run in under a minute rather than taking several hours).

Comment: Hoooly! I was so much overcomplicating solution. Thank you very much! Yes. cipher is "C" binary that works with stdin. I can pipe input to it. And thanks for explanation.